# mysqli вывод по одной записи

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день. Есть база такого формата

```
Структура: 
id - цифры (идут не всегда по порядку)
text - mediumtext (тут какая то цитата)
```

Задача в том, чтобы выводить их по очереди по 1 записи. А точнее при нажатии кнопки "Следующая" должна вывестись следующая запись с базы данных. Так как id не всегда по порядку, то столкнулся с проблемой реализации, так как с БД еще мало знаком.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: вы выберите первый  `id`, который больше текущего, и не важно будет, есть пропуски или нет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам стоит прочитать про это
http://postgresql.ru.net/manual/queries-limit.html

```
$sql = 'SELECT `id`, `text` FROM `comments` WHERE 1 LIMIT 1 OFFSET.$page;
```

Вообще советую не пилить велосипед и использовать Doctrine

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

Так как запросы в php весьма сложны в обслуживании.

Comment: про доктрину эт ты конечно хорошо завернул, но, судя по его вопросу, ему ещё далеко до неё

Comment: Да, сейчас жестче стало, так что best practices лучше использовать. Ну http://www.php-fig.org/psr/. Думаю далековато, но лучше свой уровень осознавать сразу.

Comment: А еще лучше почувствовать боль прямых запросов, https://laracasts.com/series/php-for-beginners там у них курс есть по типу сделать простую страничку. Если потом развивать её, там будет дикая боль с местным драйвером, по сему или крутить драйвер нужно, или фрейворк. Без этого обслуживание будет просто адом.

Comment: Да не жёстко ничего. Сколько компашек на 5.4 сидят до сих пор и толком ничего не знают, даже о композере. Так что если и не в ORM, то [SafeMySQL](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) вполне неплохой вариант для мускула.

Comment: Ну у них когнитивный диссонанс происходит, хотят быстрее работать, но не могут себе позволить переход на современные технологии.

Comment: Да и к сожалению они подвергают данные своих пользователей утечкой персональных данных.Так что стоит работать.

Comment: Спасибо, а не подскажите как бы это дело еще вывести с учетом пола. То есть в таблице есть поле sex которое равно 1 если это парень и 2 если девушка. Требуется в зависимости от пола выводить анкеты противоположного пола. Пробовал и WHERE age=2 и WHERE 1 AND age=2 но так тогда вообще не работает.

Comment: 'SELECT `id`, `text` FROM `comments` WHERE 1 AND sex ='male' LIMIT 1 OFFSET.$page;

Comment: К сожалению так не хочет он работать. `$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM svk_bot_profile WHERE 1 AND sex=2 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0")`

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо. У меня там проверка условий была не верна, поэтому не доходило до выборки

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67525/discussion-between-vasilyuk-dmitry-and-slander).

Answer (score 4):

Не обязательно делать выборку по id. Записи в БД хранятся в порядке добавления и этим порядком можно воспользоваться.

Предположим что таблица называется comments, тогда использует такой запрос:

```
SELECT `id`, `text` FROM `comments` WHERE 1 LIMIT 0, 1
```

Ключевое здесь - LIMIT 0, 1 где 1 - это кол-во строк, а 0 - отступ.
Если изменить на `LIMIT 2, 1`, то мы получим только 3 строку из таблицы. LIMIT работает уже после WHERE, ORDER BY и GROUP BY